# A question involving inner product on a Hilbert Space

Tags: inner-products

Let $H$ be a hilbert space, and let $x,y \in H$. If $\langle x,z \rangle=\langle y,z\rangle$ for all $z \in H$, then $x=y$.

Is this statement true or false? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is true. Intuitively, this says that all "coordinates" of $x$ and $y$ are equal. A formal proof would proceed as follows:

From the given condition: $\langle(x-y),z\rangle=0$ for all $z \in H$. Now, take $z=(x-y)$ to get $||x-y||^2=0$ where $||\cdot||$ is induced by the inner product.

Now, one of the axioms that a norm has to satisfy (to be induced from a inner product on a Hilbert space) is that $||z||=0$ if and only if $z=0$. So from above we get that $x-y=0$, i.e. $x=y.$

Comment: Thanks, that was great. one thing tho, x-y is in H because H is complete?

Comment: @ChuckP: You are welcome. Also- welcome to the site, and if you found my answer useful, could you please "accept" it by ticking the "arrow"? :)

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote, I would do it for sure if I could. I've also edited my comment.

Comment: @ChuckP: $x-y$ is in $H$ as $H$ is a vector space. 

Also- didn't ask you to upvote- only to accept an answer- whichever you find useful- and there's no hurry. Just wanted to give you a heads up about the norms of the community. :).

Comment: oh, that's true. I also didn't see that arrow over there. I've accepted the answer now, thanks again :D

Comment: @ChuckP: Thanks :). Hopefully you shall find the community useful.